# Json.net dynamic brackets without name

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, json.net

Can you create brackets using dynamic json without the name of the list/array appearing in the json string?  Otherwise I will need to rewrite entire section.

The problem is i haven't figured out how to create brackets in dymanic json without having a name that comes before it. In my json string, values will have a parent bracket wrapping all its entries, then a bracket wrapping the timestamp and another bracket wrapping the books. **The brackets wrapping timestamp & books should not have names appearing in front of them.**

Using this [link](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing), I got very close to the format I want but I'm missing the bracket separation for time and the remaining entries.

sample code:

```
JObject jsonobject = new JObject();
JObject jsonobject2 = new JObject();
dynamic topObject = jsonobject;
topObject.records = new JArray() as dynamic;
dynamic midObject = jsonobject2;
midObject.value = new JArray() as dynamic;
dynamic record = new JObject();
record.TIMESTAMP = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
record.ID = "sampleid";
midObject.value.Add(record);
//query for data
//loop through query
// add to record when data found ex:record.author=dr[0].ToString();
// midObject.value.Add(record);
// finished add data from query
topObject.records.Add(midObject);

string jsonstr = topObject.ToString();
```

current output:

```
{
"records": [
{
"value": [
{
"TIMESTAMP": "January 03 2017 09:46:15",
"ID": "sampleID"
},
{
"Title": "Book2",
"Author": "author1"
},
{
"Title": "Book1"
"Author": "author1"
"Notes": "testtest"
}
]
}
]
}
```

desired output:

```
{
"records": [
{
"value": [
[ ------->bracket wrapping timestamp
{
"TIMESTAMP": "January 03 2017 09:46:15",
"ID": "sampleID"
}
] ------->bracket wrapping timestamp
,
[ ------->bracket wrapping books 
{
"Title": "Book2",
"Artist": "artist1"
},
{
"Title": "Book1"
"Artist": "artist1"
"Notes": "testtest"
}
] ------->bracket wrapping books 
] 
}
]
}
```

edit: May have oversimplified but books section has 20+ fields. Each json string will only have one timestamp but can have 100's -1,000's of books per request.

edit2: title / clarification on the main question.

Comment: Use an object parser with DTO Classes.The code you are creating is highly unmaintainable.

Comment: The square bracket you desire on your timestamp object denotes a collection/array. Changing the type to a collection (List<T>/Array[]/IEnumerable<>) will likely achieve the desired JSON format however it will alter the inner workings of your objects.

Comment: Brackets indicate arrays in the [JSON specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). Unless your timestamps and books are likely to occur multiple times, in the interest of maintainability like @DanielCarbajalLópez mentioned, keep away from this.

Comment: As for excluding empty elements, you can ignore properties that are `null` to be excluded from serialisation using the [NullValueHandling enum](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) option in a [JsonSerializerSettings](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) class.

Comment: @Gigabyte Timestamp only appears once at the very top.  Books can have hunderds/thousands of entries in the same json string.  
I don't want to use the brackets to separate the timestamp and books but they were part of the project requirements.

Comment: @MADnoobie So it makes sense to use `[` and `]` around your books as it is an `array` of Book elements. However, the object containing an ID and TIMESTAMP is not an array. I doubt if any non-manual parsing would be okay with this. Suggest to try and convince your requirements analyst that it may look nice, but is definitely non-conformative. ;-)

Comment: @Gigabyte =D I'll try to see if I can convince the requirements to change but that's unlikely since it seems they already have a reader to deserialize the results in this format.
I understand that arrays translate to brackets in json but the main question I should have clarified -: is there a way to use Dynamic json to create brackets(without a name) otherwise, I will have to rewrite the entire thing.  Dynamic Json tends to write the name of the list/array before inserting the brackets.  I just want the bracket w/out the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you just need to add another array for all the records:

```
JObject jsonobject = new JObject();
JObject jsonobject2 = new JObject();
dynamic topObject = jsonobject;
topObject.records = new JArray() as dynamic;
dynamic midObject = jsonobject2;
midObject.value = new JArray() as dynamic;
dynamic arrayrecord = new JArray();
dynamic record = new JObject();
record.TIMESTAMP = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
record.ID = "sampleid";
arrayrecord.Add(record);
midObject.value.Add(arrayrecord);
//query for data
//loop through query
// add to record when data found ex:record.author=dr[0].ToString();
// midObject.value.Add(record);
// finished add data from query
topObject.records.Add(midObject);

string jsonstr = topObject.ToString();
```

Comment: Your solution worked.
Edit: thought there was syntax error.

Comment: What was the error? That code worked in LinqPad and produced the right output. oh, nevermind XD